# How can i change a wordpress theme default height?

Tags: wordpress-theming, twentytwenty

I'm using twenty twenty theme in word press to bulid website and i cant fit content in the home page cause it had a default height and i can't change it for mobile version if any one can help ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq0yV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the content width.
Here is a code:

```
.container{
 `Number`%;
}
```

And Here is a link to a potential solution to the mobile version of your website:
https://wpklik.com/wordpress-tutorials/how-to-edit-mobile-version-of-wordpress-site/